# Navigation Menu in Support Action Bar not opening

Tags: android

EDIT: So the menu exists but I can only get to it by sliding the menu out, the button on the top left corner doesn't toggle the drawer open.

I'm trying to implement a nav menu but instead of a hamburger button showing that opens my menu, I'm left with a non-functioning back button. I'm assuming it's a little different than the Nav Button tutorial Google has due to using a toolbar as my action bar.

MainActivity.java:

```
private CharSequence mTitle;
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    FrameLayout frameLayout;
    DrawerLayout Drawer;                                  // Declaring DrawerLayout
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;                  // Declaring Action Bar Drawer Toggle

    String TITLES[];
    int ICONS[] = {R.drawable.drawer_back, R.drawable.drawer_settings,R.drawable.drawer_notifications, R.drawable.drawer_feedback};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TITLES = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_array);
        mTitle = getTitle();
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar); // Attaching the layout to the toolbar object
        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                R.layout.item_row, TITLES));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,Drawer,R.string.openDrawer,R.string.closeDrawer){

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

        };
    }
```

main_activity.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar"
            ></include>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/gm_header"
            layout="@layout/gm_header"
            ></include>

        <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
             space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
        <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">


                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0"/>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/ColorPrimaryDark"
                    android:layout_weight="0"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Do you mean a "non-functional UP button" instead of back? Note that the arrow up on the upper left corner is called UP..

Comment: Whatever you want to to call the button that looks like: <--

Comment: Yeah, so that's the UP button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there's two DrawerLayouts declared, one called *Drawer* and one called *mDrawerLayout*. I'm going to use *mDrawerLayout*.

In the Drawer Toggle constructor, you can associate the toggle with the DrawerLayout and the Toolbar by declaring it with `mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer){
// rest of code`

Then add another couple of lines

If you want the icon to change between a hamburger and an arrow when the drawer opens and closes use this listener:

```
  mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

call syncState to put the button and drawer into the same state(open or closed):

```
  mDrawerToggle.syncState();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve proper "back" navigation by handling the click events of the menu items. The one you're talking about in Android is referred as the Up button which is known as the `home` menu item. Add this code to your `Activity` and you'll be able to go back from the current Activity to the previous one:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Now there are way better ways to handle the UP navigation than this. This approach simply kills the current `Activity` you see which will end up behaving like a back navigation as you'd like to call it.

Please refer to [this section](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html) from the Android documentation to understand what's the difference between

Back:

[image: back]

and Up:

[image: up]

Once you understand the difference, you can check out [this section](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) to understand how the proper Up navigation should be handled.

Cheers!